# Android Saving a file to internal memory works while to Sd card fails

Tags: android, file, file-io, sd-card

I have an Android app where I need to save a file.
I create the file like this:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, 
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
```

I open it like this:

```
FileInputStream srcFileStream = openFileInput(fileName);
```

This works fine with internal memory files.
I've added a prefrences to my app, where the user can select to save the file to the sd card instead.
I try this command:

```
if (Prefs.getCard(this))
        fileName="/sdcard/"+fileName;
```

Meaning that if the Prefrences is yes, I add "/sdcard/" infront of the file name.
The rest of the code remains the same,

This does not seem to work, as I get an Exception:

```
File /sd/file1 contains a path seperator
```

How can I use the same code for both saving to SD card and to internal memory, with just a small modification as i tried above?

Comment: You have to open the stream the plain old Java way. File operations of `Context` don't allow subdiretories and only work inside your internal app directory

Comment: When I do so i get: open failed: EACCES (Permision denied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work..

```
String baseDir = "";
String fileName = "myFile.txt";
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
if (Prefs.getCard(this)) {
    baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(baseDir + fileName);
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file)
}  else {
    fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
}
if (fOut != null) {
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This gives me the sd path? but what about internal? I need a solution for both

Comment: no it gives the path /mt/sd/filename while the internal is something else.

Comment: yep thats what i did at the end

Answer (score 3):

You certainly didn't forget to add the right permission in the manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can also try to access the external path using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

I've already seen different external path name, depending on the device...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit was beaten to it by Sevens:**

You could try something like this:

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
String fullfilename = f.getAbsoluteFile() + "/Android/data/NameOfApp/fileshere/" ;

File folderToWrite = new File(fullfilename);
folderToWrite.mkdirs();

File fileToWrite = new File(fullfilename,"filename.txt");
```

Comment: I dont understand, The file path goes  to the SD or to the internal?